# how to filter multiple messages in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

so i recently did a filter for messages so as to bring all the messages between two people

```
def pmessage(request, pk):
     user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
     message = pm.objects.filter(Q(receiver=request.user, sender=user) | Q(receiver=user, sender=request.user))
     form = dmform()
     context = {
          'message' : message,
          'form' : form,
     }
```

it works, only that it groups the messages in categories ie, it would list all the messages that meets one criteria before the other irrespective of which message came first, and that defeats my aim.

thanks you

Edited
Pm model

```
class pm(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='receiver', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)    body = models.TextField()
    unread = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'sender:{self.sender} - receiver:{self.receiver} - {self.body}'
```

Comment: Can you share the `pm` model?

Comment: I edited the initial question to add the pm model

Comment: so you want to retrieve the messages ordered by the `created` date? (or `updated`)?

Comment: created, but it should come in a conversation manner, i sent you a message 'a', you replied 'b' and 'c' then i sent 'd' so it should come A,B,C,D not A,D,B,C which is how it currently does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order the messages with `.order_by('created')`:

```
def pmessage(request, pk):
    message = pm.objects.filter(
        Q(receiver=request.user, sender_id=pk) |
        Q(receiver_id=pk, sender=request.user)
    ).order_by('created')
    form = dmform()
    context = {
        'message' : message,
        'form' : form,
    }
```

Comment: i have one more issue with a different view but same project